# Classifying samples from complex Gaussian distributions

Tags: gaussian, classification

Assume we are trying to classify a sample $X$ as coming from one of two distributions:
$$
\mathcal{CN}(\mu, \sigma^2) \\
\mathcal{CN}(\nu, \sigma^2),
$$
where $\mathcal{CN}$ denotes a (circularly symmetric) complex Gaussian distribution with total noise variance $\sigma^2$, meaning it has $\sigma^2/2$ variance across the real and imaginary components.

In the real-valued case, the classification performance depends only on the SNR of the problem, also called the detectability i.e.
$$d' = \frac{\lVert \mu - \nu \rVert_2^2}{\sigma^2}.$$

Intuitively, this should be identical in the complex case as the total noise power is $\sigma^2$. However, when I do the likelihood ratio calculations treating the complex Gaussian as a bi-variate Gausian with covariance matrix $\pmatrix{\sigma^2/2 &0 \\0 & \sigma^2/2}$, the result comes out to be
$$d' = \frac{2\lVert \mu - \nu \rVert_2^2}{\sigma^2}.$$

Now, I think something's wrong here. The total variance is $\sigma^2$ since the complex-valued Gaussian is not just a multivariate Gaussian and the real and imaginary part of the signal are "joined" in one complex number. Why does this factor $2$ pop up and how can I get rid of it? Is there a special way to calculate the detectability for a complex-valued problem where I have to use the trace of the covariance matrix in the denominator? If yes, can someone maybe point me to some relevant literature on the topic?

Comment: Didn't you ask essentially the same question in https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/84242/235?

Comment: I would not say they are essentially the same when one deals with the KL divergence and the other with detectability and their only similarity is the factor 2 issue, but if you/the community feel strongly about it, I am happy to merge the questions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something here but given that a circularly symmetric complex normal RV X can be broken down into two independent real normal RVs (I+jQ), the complex RV classification problem can be split up into two separate real classification problems, as you showed above - except that each now has variance $\sigma_2/2$. Thus the detectability for each problem is trivially scaled by 2.

However I guess that is still not the same as the detectability for the overall problem. But, given that the two problems are independent, I would think you can show something like:

$P(\text{correctly classify }X) = P(\text{correctly classify } I \text{ AND correctly classify } Q) = P(\text{correctly classify } I) \cdot P(\text{correctly classify } Q)$